# java.lang.SecurityException on add JMXConnection in jvisulavm

Tags: java, debugging, jmx, jvisualvm, securityexception

Hello Fellow developers,

I am trying to open up a jmx connection to an application using jvisualvm, but when I add the connection it fails with SecurityException. Can anyone help me figure out how I can avoid this?

Full stack trace

```
SEVERE [org.openide.util.RequestProcessor]: Error in RequestProcessor com.sun.tools.visualvm.jmx.impl.AddJMXConnectionAction$1
java.lang.SecurityException: attempt to add a Permission to a readonly Permissions object
        at java.security.Permissions.add(Permissions.java:126)
        at java.security.Policy$UnsupportedEmptyCollection.add(Policy.java:827)
        at sun.rmi.server.LoaderHandler.getLoaderAccessControlContext(LoaderHandler.java:1005)
        at sun.rmi.server.LoaderHandler.lookupLoader(LoaderHandler.java:881)
        at sun.rmi.server.LoaderHandler.loadClass(LoaderHandler.java:404)
        at sun.rmi.server.LoaderHandler.loadClass(LoaderHandler.java:186)
        at java.rmi.server.RMIClassLoader$2.loadClass(RMIClassLoader.java:637)
        at java.rmi.server.RMIClassLoader.loadClass(RMIClassLoader.java:264)
        at sun.rmi.server.MarshalInputStream.resolveClass(MarshalInputStream.java:219)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNonProxyDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1866)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readClassDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1749)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2040)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1571)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:431)
        at sun.rmi.server.UnicastRef.unmarshalValue(UnicastRef.java:322)
        at sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.unmarshalParametersUnchecked(UnicastServerRef.java:628)
        at sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.unmarshalParameters(UnicastServerRef.java:616)
        at sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.dispatch(UnicastServerRef.java:338)
        at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:200)
        at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:197)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at sun.rmi.transport.Transport.serviceCall(Transport.java:196)
        at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport.handleMessages(TCPTransport.java:573)
        at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run0(TCPTransport.java:835)
        at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.lambda$run$0(TCPTransport.java:688)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run(TCPTransport.java:687)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
        at sun.rmi.transport.StreamRemoteCall.exceptionReceivedFromServer(StreamRemoteCall.java:283)
        at sun.rmi.transport.StreamRemoteCall.executeCall(StreamRemoteCall.java:260)
        at sun.rmi.server.UnicastRef.invoke(UnicastRef.java:161)
        at com.sun.jmx.remote.internal.PRef.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl_Stub.isInstanceOf(Unknown Source)
        at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnector$RemoteMBeanServerConnection.isInstanceOf(RMIConnector.java:1100)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at com.sun.tools.visualvm.jmx.impl.JmxModelImpl$CheckerInvocationHandler.invoke(JmxModelImpl.java:655)
        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy11.isInstanceOf(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.management.ManagementFactory.newPlatformMXBeanProxy(ManagementFactory.java:617)
        at com.sun.tools.visualvm.tools.jmx.JvmMXBeansFactory$JvmMXBeansImpl.getMXBean(JvmMXBeansFactory.java:363)
        at com.sun.tools.visualvm.tools.jmx.JvmMXBeansFactory$JvmMXBeansImpl.getRuntimeMXBean(JvmMXBeansFactory.java:336)
        at com.sun.tools.visualvm.jmx.impl.JmxApplication.getPid(JmxApplication.java:64)
        at com.sun.tools.visualvm.jvmstat.JvmstatModelProvider.getMonitoredVm(JvmstatModelProvider.java:29)
        at com.sun.tools.visualvm.jvmstat.JvmstatModelProvider.createModelFor(JvmstatModelProvider.java:51)
        at com.sun.tools.visualvm.jvmstat.JvmstatModelProvider.createModelFor(JvmstatModelProvider.java:25)
        at com.sun.tools.visualvm.core.model.ModelFactory.getModel(ModelFactory.java:91)
        at com.sun.tools.visualvm.tools.jvmstat.JvmstatModelFactory.getJvmstatFor(JvmstatModelFactory.java:45)
        at com.sun.tools.visualvm.jvm.JRockitJvmProvider.createModelFor(JRockitJvmProvider.java:29)
        at com.sun.tools.visualvm.jvm.JRockitJvmProvider.createModelFor(JRockitJvmProvider.java:22)
        at com.sun.tools.visualvm.core.model.ModelFactory.getModel(ModelFactory.java:91)
        at com.sun.tools.visualvm.application.jvm.JvmFactory.getJVMFor(JvmFactory.java:45)
        at com.sun.tools.visualvm.jmx.impl.JmxApplicationProvider.addJmxApplication(JmxApplicationProvider.java:303)
        at com.sun.tools.visualvm.jmx.impl.JmxApplicationProvider.createJmxApplication(JmxApplicationProvider.java:186)
        at com.sun.tools.visualvm.jmx.JmxApplicationsSupport.createJmxApplicationImpl(JmxApplicationsSupport.java:299)
        at com.sun.tools.visualvm.jmx.JmxApplicationsSupport.createJmxApplicationInteractive(JmxApplicationsSupport.java:276)
        at com.sun.tools.visualvm.jmx.impl.AddJMXConnectionAction$1.run(AddJMXConnectionAction.java:60)
        at org.openide.util.RequestProcessor$Task.run(RequestProcessor.java:1384)
[catch] at org.openide.util.RequestProcessor$Processor.run(RequestProcessor.java:1994)
```

Any help appreciated.

Comment: This looks like an 8 years old (!) bug in OpenJDK: https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8014008. It might be caused by simply configuring some *policy* for an Java app, but I'm not sure. What application are you trying to connect to?

Answer (score 1):

Do you have SecurityManager inside your app code?

```
@Override
public PermissionCollection getPermissions(ProtectionDomain domain) {}
```

that could return immutable list.
In my case that's caused the same exception.